# Is it possible to detect UIAccessibility notifications in my app like VoiceOver does?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I want my IOS app to be able to log UI actions (touching on views). I thought about using UIAccessibility notifications. Is it possible to detect these notifications inside my app like VoiceOver does?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry if it is a stupid question. Maybe it is against Apple secure policy, I don't know. I just got a task and want to do it in elegant way - without adding logging to each UI method of my app

Comment: loggin the actions is different than reading them out. If you want to read the actions like voice over, yes you can do that.